# PHPSpreedsheat reduce memory in phpunittest

Tags: php, phpunit, phpspreadsheet

I have noticed when using php spreadsheet it adds around 40MB everytime it is called which leads to my unit test running out of memory and failing. I have tried to disconnect and unset but does not make any difference. I do not want to use any external caching. My version is:

> "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.6"

When i unit test with alot of function in the same file it runs out of memory  increasing memory is not an option. i would like to know how i can reduce the memory usage.

```
  echo __CLASS__ . ' : ' . __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB' , EOL;

        $saveFile = '';
        $response = [];
        /**
         * default save file location
         */
        if (file_exists($CFG->cmsavedir) && is_writable($CFG->cmsavedir) && file_exists($CFG->cmtemplate) && is_readable($CFG->cmtemplate)) {

            try {
                /**
                 * cell border style
                 */
                $borderStyle = array(
                    'borders' => array(
                        'allborders' => array(
                            'style' => Border::BORDER_THIN
                        ),
                        'vertical' => array(
                            'style' => Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
                        )
                    )
                );

                $fileType = IOFactory::identify($CFG->cmtemplate);

                $objReader = IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($CFG->cmtemplate);
       
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('FW Matrix');
                echo __CLASS__ . ' : ' . __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB' , EOL;
                foreach ($content as $row) {
                    echo __CLASS__ . ' : ' . __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB' , EOL;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("A$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['status'])) ? $row['status'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("B$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['source'])) ? $row['source'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("C$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['src_desc'])) ? $row['src_desc'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['destination'])) ? $row['destination'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("E$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['dst_desc'])) ? $row['dst_desc'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['ports'])) ? $row['ports'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("G$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['nattype'])) ? $row['nattype'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("H$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['nat'])) ? $row['nat'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("I$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['protocol'])) ? $row['protocol'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("J$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['environment'])) ? $row['environment'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("K$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['service_grouping'])) ? $row['service_grouping'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("L$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['track'])) ? $row['track'] : '');
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("M$cmTemplateRow", (isset($row['remarks'])) ? $row['remarks'] : '');

  
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->getStyle("A$cmTemplateRow:S$cmTemplateRow")
                        ->applyFromArray($borderStyle);

                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->getStyle("A$cmTemplateRow:S$cmTemplateRow")
                        ->getAlignment()
                        ->setVertical(Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->getStyle("A$cmTemplateRow:S$cmTemplateRow")
                        ->getAlignment()
                        ->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);

                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->getRowDimension($cmTemplateRow)
                        ->setRowHeight(- 1);
                    $cmTemplateRow ++;
                }

     
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getStyle('B')
                    ->getAlignment()
                    ->setWrapText(true);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getStyle('D')
                    ->getAlignment()
                    ->setWrapText(true);

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B5', 'All underlined fields are mandatory fields !!!');


                echo __CLASS__ . ' : ' . __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB' , EOL;

                $objWriter = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

                if (! empty($filename)) {
                    $filename = $filename . '.xlsx';
                } else {
                    $filename = 'FW-Sample-' . preg_replace('/\s/', '_', $service) . '-Simple_' . date('YmdHis') . '.xlsx';
                }

                $saveFile = $CFG->uploaddir . "/$filename";

                $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');
                $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);                

                if (file_exists($saveFile)) {
                    unlink($saveFile);
                }
                $objWriter->save($saveFile);
                echo __CLASS__ . ' : ' . __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB' , EOL;
            } catch (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception $e) {
                ...
            }
        } else {
    ...
        }
        $objPHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
        $objPHPExcel->__destruct();
        unset($objPHPExcel);
        unset($objWriter);
        echo __CLASS__ . ' : ' . __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB' , EOL;
```

my echo responses are

```
Simple\SimpleExcel : 40 : 18 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel : 117 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel : 120 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel : 186 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel : 210 : 79.50390625 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel : 223 : 79.50390625 MB
```

You can see it start low and just starts to go up.

UPDATE

new changes in code

```
echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
        global $CFG;

        $this->log->debug('service: ' . $service);
        $this->log->debug('filename: ' . $filename);
        $this->log->debug($content);

        //$cmTemplateStartRow = 9;
        if (! isset($CFG->cmtemplaterow)) {
            $cmTemplateRow = 9;
        } else {
            $cmTemplateRow = $CFG->cmtemplaterow;
            //$cmTemplateStartRow = $CFG->cmtemplaterow;
        }

        $this->log->debug('cmsavedir: ' . $CFG->cmsavedir);
        $this->log->debug('cmtemplate: ' . $CFG->cmtemplate);

        if(!is_writable($CFG->cmsavedir)) {
            $this->log->error($CFG->cmsavedir . ' is not writable!');
        }

        if(!file_exists($CFG->cmtemplate)) {
            $this->log->error($CFG->cmtemplate . ' does not exist!');
        }

        if(!is_readable($CFG->cmtemplate)) {
            $this->log->error($CFG->cmtemplate . ' is not readable!');
        }

        $saveFile = '';
        $response = [];
        /**
         * default save file location
         */
        if (file_exists($CFG->cmsavedir) && is_writable($CFG->cmsavedir) && file_exists($CFG->cmtemplate) && is_readable($CFG->cmtemplate)) {

            try {
                /**
                 * cell border style
                 */
                $borderStyle = array(
                    'borders' => array(
                        'allborders' => array(
                            'style' => Border::BORDER_THIN
                        ),
                        'vertical' => array(
                            'style' => Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
                        )
                    )
                );

                if(CACHE_ON){
                    $client = new \Redis();
                    $client->connect(CACHE_HOST, 6379);
                    $pool = new \Cache\Adapter\Redis\RedisCachePool($client);
                    $simpleCache = new \Cache\Bridge\SimpleCache\SimpleCacheBridge($pool);
                    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings::setCache($simpleCache);
                }

                /**
                 * identify template worksheet file type
                 */
                $fileType = IOFactory::identify($CFG->cmtemplate);
                echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                /**
                 * create reader of worksheet file type
                 */
                $objReader = IOFactory::createReader($fileType);

                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($CFG->cmtemplate);

                /**
                 * set active sheet
                 */
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('FW Matrix');
                $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
                $style = $sheet
                ->getStyle("A$cmTemplateRow:S$cmTemplateRow");
                echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                foreach ($content as $row) {
                    //$this->log->debug($row);
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("A$cmTemplateRow", $row['status'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("B$cmTemplateRow", $row['source'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("C$cmTemplateRow", $row['src_desc'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("D$cmTemplateRow", $row['destination'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("E$cmTemplateRow", $row['dst_desc'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("F$cmTemplateRow", $row['ports'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("G$cmTemplateRow", $row['nattype'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("H$cmTemplateRow", $row['nat'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("I$cmTemplateRow", $row['protocol'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("J$cmTemplateRow", $row['environment'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("K$cmTemplateRow", $row['service_grouping'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("L$cmTemplateRow", $row['track'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $sheet->setCellValue("M$cmTemplateRow", $row['remarks'] ?? '');
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;

                    /**
                     * set row border
                     */
                    $style
                    ->applyFromArray($borderStyle);
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;

                    /**
                     * set align top left
                     */
                    $style
                        ->getAlignment()
                        ->setVertical(Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
                        echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                    $style
                        ->getAlignment()
                        ->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
                        echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;

                    /**
                     * autosize height
                     */
                    $sheet
                        ->getRowDimension($cmTemplateRow)
                        ->setRowHeight(- 1);
                        $cmTemplateRow ++;
                        echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                }

                /**
                 * wrap text
                 */
                $sheet
                    ->getStyle('B')
                    ->getAlignment()
                    ->setWrapText(true);
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;
                $sheet
                    ->getStyle('D')
                    ->getAlignment()
                    ->setWrapText(true);
                    echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;

                $sheet->setCellValue('B5', 'All underlined fields are mandatory fields !!!');

                /**
                 * create writer object
                 */
                $objWriter = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

                /**
                 * define save file
                 */
                if (! empty($filename)) {
                    $filename = $filename . '.xlsx';
                } else {
                    $filename = 'FW-Sample-' . preg_replace('/\s/', '_', $service) . '-Simple_' . date('YmdHis') . '.xlsx';
                }

                $saveFile = $CFG->uploaddir . "/$filename";

                $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Xlsx');
                $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);

                if (file_exists($saveFile)) {
                    unlink($saveFile);
                }
                $objWriter->save($saveFile);
                $this->log->info("File created $saveFile");
            } catch (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Exception $e) {
                $response['error'] = true;
                $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = ' Could not create CM file';
        }
        echo __CLASS__ . ':'. __LINE__ . ' : ' . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . ' MB', EOL;

        $response['recordset']['filename'] = $saveFile;
        return $response;
```

memory echo statements reflected above

```
Simple\SimpleExcel:41 : 20 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:105 : 20 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:120 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:123 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:125 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:127 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:129 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:131 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:133 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:135 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:137 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:139 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:141 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:143 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:145 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:147 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:149 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:156 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:164 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:168 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:177 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:187 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:192 : 59 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:228 : 79.50390625 MB
```

with redis cache i get following result which saves about 10MB. but i don't have caching set up yet and would like to save MB using no cache if possible. The only other option is to split up all my tests in phpunit so they all run separately and not in one class file

```
if(CACHE_ON){
                    $client = new \Redis();
                    $client->connect(CACHE_HOST, 6379);
                    $pool = new \Cache\Adapter\Redis\RedisCachePool($client);
                    $simpleCache = new \Cache\Bridge\SimpleCache\SimpleCacheBridge($pool);
                    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Settings::setCache($simpleCache);
                }

Simple\SimpleExcel:41 : 20 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:105 : 20 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:120 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:123 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:125 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:127 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:129 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:131 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:133 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:135 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:137 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:139 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:141 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:143 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:145 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:147 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:149 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:156 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:164 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:168 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:177 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:187 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:192 : 42.5 MB
Simple\SimpleExcel:231 : 66.5078125 MB
```

Comment: Which call exactly adds the 40MB? You should probably set `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()` to a variable instead of calling the `getActiveSheet()` function x times in the test.

Comment: at the start of this function with 18 mb and end up with 79mb. thats extra 60mb. if i can reduce somehow

Comment: Just to get some perspective ... How many entries are you adding (`count($content)`) and how large is original the excel file [MB]? Did you try saving the active sheet in a variable? If yes what's the result?

Comment: the for loop is 2 rows. the file being loaded is 448K which is being filled in on the loop. after file is created it is 188K

Comment: using `$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();` made no difference

Comment: At least it cleans up the code a bit and prevents *"some"* unnecessary calls. Consider using the null coalesce operator instead of the `isset($row[x]) : $row[x] ? ''` statements to further clean up the code. You can use `$row[x] ?? ''` instead. Further slim down the 3 `getStyle` calls at the end of the loop by saving the result in a variable. Add another memory-usage dump in between the `setCellValue` calls and the style settings and report back please. This will help finding the memory expensive call(s).

Comment: i have updated the the code with results

Comment: To me this looks like it's either the `createReader()` or the `load()` call that's consuming the memory here. Did you try to `unset()` those 2 variables (`$objReader` and `$objPHPExcel`) at the end of the method?

Comment: Trying `unset` is a good suggestion. If you look at the `$objReader` object you will see that it is quite large and only gets larger when you start using it and loading spreadsheets etc.

Comment: I have added `unset($objReader);` straight after `load` and destruct and unset to `$objPHPExcel` at end of method but made no difference in memory